# Communication between two Python files

Tags: python, import

I'm having a problem with importing files which can be simplified as this:

a.py:

```
import b

a = 0
b.foo()
```

b.py:

```
import a

def foo():
    a.a=4
```

So, what I'm trying to do is: in file a.py call the function foo() from b.py which would then change the value of a variable that is in a.py. This is the error I get:

> AttributeError: module 'b' has no attribute 'foo'

What am I doing wrong? What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: you have a cicular import...

Comment: are both the files in the same location ?

Comment: yes. Import either of them to one. This will fix your problem.

Comment: its loop. you running `a.py` and `a.py` import `b.py` and `b.py` import 'a.py', so it is not good programming to create this type of loop in code.

Comment: They are in the same location. Importing just one of them doesn't work, the method in b.py just creates a new variable 'a' in it's scope.

Answer (score 2):

your [import is circular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python). you need to come up with a way of testing that with a non-circular import. e.g. create a new main file that you execute; import `a.a` and `b.foo` there:

`main.py`

```
from b import foo
import a

a.a = 7
foo()
```

`a.py`

```
a = 0
```

`b.py`

```
import a

def foo():
    a.a=4
```

Comment: But how do I address the variable 'a' in b.py then?

Comment: @Njubster added an example.

Comment: So, does that mean that the thing that I'm asking for is not doable without the third file?

Comment: what is not doable is to import a from b and b from a at the same time. that is what is called a circular import.

Comment: Ok, thanks man, I guess I'll try to avoid doing the circular thingie.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost thing is making circular import, and fixing it is not a good idea.

But try to do small change in your code and solve.

a.py:

```
from b import foo

a = 0
foo()
print a
```

b.py:

```
def foo():
    import a as filea
    filea.a=4
```

when you run a.py, watch the `print a`, it is executing two times. You need to be at your own risk by fixing lot of such things.
Instead of doing all circus, better to avoid circular import.

Comment: I'm curious, what's the risk?

Comment: all your globals `a.py` will be called multiple times is one point.

Comment: @Njubster You can try to use `pycharm`, and debug step by step, and see the flow, you will get to know more clear, what is happening, with this two files code.